# Object colors disappear after diselect

Tags: materials

I select an object, choose the colors I want and everything seems good. Except, when I select another object, the colors just disappear, come back to the old ones. I don't know what is happening to be honest, but it just started right now. I haven't had the problem till now.

[image]
[image]
As you can see, the colors stay just when I select the object. What’s happening and can it be fixed?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! That's really weird. Does it change back if you select your original object?

Comment: No, unfortunatly, it doesnt

Comment: What happens if you undo?

Comment: Send the scene please so we could expect. When U try to make another scene from scratch and test it the problem still persist?

Answer (score 1):

You have a copy of object in exact same place.

[image]

When z-buffer is same blender displays selected object on top of deselected.